# BeginContact not being executed

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm trying to detect a collision between a dynamic and a static body. The code I wrote executes without any errors but the collision is not being detected. The Dynamic body is movable. When it touches other bodies in the PhysicsWorld the collision is not being detected. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements ContactListener {
    Body body, bodyr1, bodyr2, bodyr3;
    PhysicsWorld pw;

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
        scene = new Scene();
        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - back.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.back.getHeight()) / 2;

        Sprite backgr = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, back,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        Sprite rcs1 = new Sprite(85, 250, rc1,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        Sprite rcs2 = new Sprite(195, 240, rc2,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        Sprite rcs3 = new Sprite(295, 250, rc3,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        ans = new AnimatedSprite(86, 245, ttr,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                @Override
                protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    this.setPosition(pX, pY);
                    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
                }
            };

        this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(ans);
        pw = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),
            false);
        final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(2f,0f, 0.9f);
        body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, ans, BodyType.DynamicBody,
            objectFixtureDef);
        bodyr1 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, rcs1, BodyType.StaticBody,
            objectFixtureDef);
        bodyr2 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, rcs2, BodyType.StaticBody,
            objectFixtureDef);
        bodyr3 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(pw, rcs3, BodyType.StaticBody,
            objectFixtureDef);

        pw.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ans, body, true, true));

        scene.attachChild(backgr);
        scene.attachChild(rcs1);
        scene.attachChild(rcs2);
        scene.attachChild(rcs3);
        scene.attachChild(ans);
        body.setUserData("player");
        bodyr2.setUserData("3");
        pw.setContactListener(this);
        scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);
    }

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        // Fixture x1= contact.getFixtureA();
        // Fixture x2=contact.getFixtureB();
        Log.i("Contacted","asdasdads");
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Why is the collision not being detected? Please help

Comment: Hoping my post may help you

Answer (score 0):

I didnot found  the contact listener in your class.I think you have to add the following link:

```
mPhysicsWorld.setContactListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help brother..but your suggestion didn't work. I modified this line scene.registerUpdateHandler(pw); to make collision work